# Ruby exclamation mark -printing next line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
TENANT_NAME=gets.chomp('/\p{Alnum}/')

$first = TENANT_NAME.slice(0,1).capitalize

$second = TENANT_NAME.slice(1..-1)

EXPORT_PASSWORD="Export-"+ $first + $second + "!"

puts EXPORT_PASSWORD
```

I want to print EXPORT_PASSWORD in one-line, but when i am trying to print it prints ! from another line. I am using Ruby
output:

```
devi123kumari
Export-Devi123kumari
!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>TENANT_NAME=gets.chomp('/\p{Alnum}/')
somename
TENANT_NAME
=> "somename\n"
```

see you are getting \n here which is shifting your ! to second line.

```
>TENANT_NAME=gets.chomp
somename
TENANT_NAME
=> "somename"
```

now you wont get the extra line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
EXPORT_PASSWORD="Export-"+ $first + $second.chomp + "!"'
```

This is because if you check the value of `$second`, it contains trailing `\n`.

Also in Ruby prepending `$` to variable names is not a standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

[`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes the given argument from the end of the string or carriage return characters (i.e. `\n`, `\r`, and `\r\n`) if no argument is given:

```
"hello".chomp                #=> "hello"
"hello\n".chomp              #=> "hello"
"hello".chomp("llo")         #=> "he"
```

Your code removes `'/\p{Alnum}/'` (that's a string, not a regexp) from the end of a string:

```
'hello/\p{Alnum}/'.chomp('/\p{Alnum}/') #=> "hello"
```

This is probably not what you want. Just use `chomp` without an argument.